# Cisco AnyConnect (VPN) connection always forgets username

Tags: network-manager, 19.04, openvpn, 19.10

Starting with Ubuntu 19.04 (maybe even before) every time I want to connect to a Cisco AnyConnect VPN profile from the Network Manager it shows certificate confirmation dialog box and asks for username again and again, but the password is saved.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 4):

The bug still exists in gnome's network manager but there is a workaround for this from RedHat folks.
https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1332491#c24

```
nmcli con mod VPNNAME vpn.secrets 'form:main:username=USERNAME','save_passwords=yes'
```

replace the VPNNAME with the name you have given to your vpn in network manager
And replace the username with the username of your vpn.

Comment: I use MATE, i dont think there is a different network manager between MATE and Gnome desktops.... I don't experience this problem on 20.04 MATE.

Comment: Nice hint - works like a charm on Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: This worked perfectly. This was driving me mad, it only remembered the password, the exact ting i didn't want it to remeber since it was a token 

Answer (score 1):

It is a bug of gnome's network manager. It has been reported [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/1838838) and [here](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell/issues/2105), so the only solution is to wait until a fix is available or to contribute to fix the bug.