# Cannot store VPN username in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: gnome, 20.04, network-manager, openvpn, bug-reporting

As documented [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1179854/cisco-anyconnect-vpn-connection-always-forgets-username), [here](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell/-/issues/2105) and [here](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell/-/issues/2105), GNOME (3.36.8) has a problem storing the usernames for VPN connections. In my case this means that every time I want to activate my (openconnect) VPN connection I have to manually supply my username. This in turn prevents me from automatically connecting to the VPN on startup without any manual interaction. I've tried supplying the username directly in the VPN connection file as suggested in [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1179854/cisco-anyconnect-vpn-connection-always-forgets-username), but it seems like the file is overwritten everytime a connection is made.

My question is if anyone knows if this bug is going to be fixed for 20.04 LTS? It looks like it was fixed for the 20.10 release of Ubuntu.

Comment: 21.04 comes at end of April lets hope.

Comment: i have no problem using openvpn in ubuntu 20.04, you can try this go to settings->network->select vpn settings-> identity-> password->click icon next to password->store password for all users
with this option vpn will connect automatically on startup and also when you turn on after sleep mode

Comment: I can't see any "passwords" field under the "identiy" tab?

Comment: can you show a screenshot ?

Comment: Ah sorry, I am using openconnect and not openvpn and that's probably why there is no password field. I managed to solve the problem tho.

Answer (score 1):

So I managed to figure it out by following advice from [this thread](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/NetworkManager/NetworkManager/-/issues/328#note_448404), Basically I had to to use the following format for my `.nmonnection` file:

```
[vnp-secrets]
form:frmLogin:realm=<realm>
form:frmLogin:username=<username>
```

So instead of using the form `form:main.username=<username>`, I changed `main` to `frmLogin`. This makes sense as my login prompt says "frmLogin", althought I am not sure what an "frmLogin" is...